# Rails 3 trouble with namespaces & custom classes (uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, module, namespaces

I have a file in my Rails 3.2.11 project called `app/queries/visible_discussions.rb` which looks like the following:

```
class VisibleDiscussions
  ...
end
```

I'd like to namespace the query so that I can call it using something like `Queries::VisibleDiscussions` so I tried to do the following:

```
module Queries
  class VisibleDiscussions
    ...
  end
end
```

However, I'm getting a `uninitialized constant Queries (NameError)` when I try to call `Queries::VisibleDiscussions` from the rails console.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you add `lib` to your autoload_paths then it will respect the namespacing under lib - `lib/query/visible_discussions.rb`

or create a new dir under app - say src and then nest your code there - `app/src/query/visible_discussions.rb`

i would use the 3rd style in your post for either of these, i.e.

```
module Query
  class VisibleDiscussions
    ...
  end
end
```

both of these solutions are annoying to me, there might be a way to tell rails to namespace directories under app, but i have no clue how it would be done

Comment: Ah gotcha. Makes sense. Annoying. Thanks! =)

Comment: Also, i think the directory name needs to match the module name. Above example is slightly off, if directory is plural then module should be also be

Comment: Yep. Figured that one out. =)

Answer (score 0):

Rails needs to know what directories to load (a part from the defaults). Try:

```
#config.application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/queries)
```

Comment: Tried. No dice. Rails 3.8+ autoloads files in the app directory by default anyway.