# rails 3 using folder name as namspace throws uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, rails-3-upgrade, scope-resolution

I'm trying to upgrade an app **from rails 2.3 to 3.0** and it has a file

```
app/utility/interface/import/import_statistics_manager.rb
```

which contains

```
class Utility::Interface::Import::ImportStatisticsManager         
//code here  
end
```

I beleive `Utility::Interface::Import` are the folder names in its file path but used as namespaces

This code works fine in rails 2.3 but when I try to run with rails 3.0.6 it throws a NameError

```
Error message:
   uninitialized constant Utility
Exception class:
   NameError
```

FYI: rails 2.3 uses ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.6 uses ruby 1.9.2

Please correct me if my understandings are not correct

Comment: Have you added the directories to your autoload path in application.rb?

Comment: I would try to add the one you mentioned in your post, too - Not all directories in the app folder are autoloaded automatically.

Comment: @dhoelzgen yes it has "config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/utility)"

Comment: @dhoelzgen please feel free to edit the post

Comment: Ok, then try to nest the modules explicitly, as shown in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348891/rails-3-trouble-with-namespaces-custom-classes-uninitialized-constant). If this doesn't help, please provide some more info on where the error occurs.

Comment: @dhoelzgen thanx man!! that post helped adding "app" folder to autoload instead of "app//utility/interface/import" fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For future reference (see comments on the question):*

It helped adding the complete `app` folder to the autoload paths.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348891/rails-3-trouble-with-namespaces-custom-classes-uninitialized-constant) for further info.